# Retrive frames from FLIR cameras using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, flir

I am trying to connect a FLIR cammera and  process the frames using OpenCV. I connect the cammera with an internet cable but the VideoCapture object was not associated to cam successfully;

```cpp
cv::VideoCapture cam(0);            

    if (cam.isOpened() == false) {                               
        std::cout << "error: capWebcam not accessed successfully\n\n";      
        _getch();                                                          
        return(0);                                                          
    }
```

It looks like OpenCv can´t find it. The internet cable serves and as a power supply for the cammera just mentioning if maybe that's relavant.
I can use the Spinnaker SDK to retrive the frames but is there someway not to use the sdk and use direcly OpenCV

Comment: With internet cable? Do you know about cameras IP-address?

Comment: I have recently used one of the FLIRs grey point camera. You should deffinatly take a look on Spinnaker SDK - its the offical SDK from FLIR - after installing the SDK you will also see the examples and documentation on how to use it with OpenCV.

Comment: I have the documentation but i can't see anythingabout OpenCV. The documentation i have is from SpinView Help. And what do you mean by install, that's just an SDK. I don't install it just add it to the projects Directories.

Comment: It is a standalone installer and it comes with spinview (API). In the install folder there are bunch of example code on how to use it including using it with opencv. Simply google "spinaker download" and you will find it

Answer (score 3):

Ok for anyone that would be interested in the future on how to work in OpenCv with imagies acquired from PointGray cameras:

The industrial cameras have their proprietary drivers, they don't use the standard video interfaces of the OS. This is normal, as these cameras are quite complex and they are generally used in more complex situations, where you need a full control over the camera.

You have to download the camera's SDK from the Point Grey site (https://www.ptgrey.com/support/downloads) and implement the capturing yourself.

Then you can transform the captured buffer into an OpenCV Mat.

```cpp
int ConvertToCVmat(ImagePtr pImage)
{
    int result = 0;
    ImagePtr convertedImage = pImage->Convert(PixelFormat_BGR8, NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);

    unsigned int XPadding = convertedImage->GetXPadding();
    unsigned int YPadding = convertedImage->GetYPadding();
    unsigned int rowsize = convertedImage->GetWidth();
    unsigned int colsize = convertedImage->GetHeight();

    //image data contains padding. When allocating Mat container size, you need to account for the X,Y image data padding. 
    Mat cvimg = cv::Mat(colsize + YPadding, rowsize + XPadding, CV_8UC3, convertedImage->GetData(), convertedImage->GetStride());
    namedWindow("current Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("current Image", cvimg);
    resizeWindow("current Image", rowsize / 2, colsize / 2);
    waitKey(1);//otherwise the image will not display...
    
    return result;
}
```

Also this is helpful https://www.flir.ca/support-center/iis/machine-vision/application-note/getting-started-with-opencv/

Comment: 'The industrial cameras have their proprietary drivers' is not entirely correct.  The computer vision cameras are USB3 vision (U3V) or GigE Vision and both are layers on GemICam standard.  OpenCV may not support this out of the box.  The U3V standards are probably better than USB video.  See: [tag:genicam].  They support better control for machine vision application, very high frame rate as well as a variety of dynamics ranges, and mapping/synchronization of multiple imaging devices.

Answer (score 0):

cv::VideoCapture cam(0); is for cameras that install on PC 
see if you can open with VLC or any other application 
you may need to open VideoCapture with RTSP connection to the camera

Comment: I can open the camera with software provided by third party. I just wanted to see if i could avoid using the SDK with open cv

Comment: if the camera broadcast with RTSP you can give opencv the RTSP connection and connect to the camera 
VideoCapture stream1("rtsp://<CAM_IP>");