# VideoCapture USB camera OpenCV2 greyscale image contrast python

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, image-capture

I am trying to get frames from a usb FLIR camera.
The video stream works fine when I view it in a separate application, everything is crisp and clear

When I capture and save the image in code however the contrast is so low as to be unusable.
I have tried converting to gray scale and doing a equalizeHist but the original image is missing so much information that the quality ended up being garbage.

So I believe the problem to be with the cV2.VideoCapture().
When I try to set the camera preferences I just get errors or no change in image outcome. The errors are all due to the camera not supporting the setting over USB as is the case with most USB cameras and the cV2.VideoCapture().

Simplified example I have been working with for debugging

```
import time
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#camera.set(Id, value)

time.sleep(1)

return_value, image = camera.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
equ = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
cv2.imwrite("cam1/FLIR1_" + str(count) + ".png", equ)
```

[Example Image Normal, taken from cheese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvQmr.jpg)

[Example Image Code, pre-hist, note you can see myself with a headset and a mic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKkE4.png)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: usually `VideoCapture(0)` means built-in webcam - and if you have built-in webcam then you may need to check different values ie.  `VideoCapture(1)`, etc.

Comment: @furas The error isn't something I am looking for help with as the error is related to the camera not support those commands over USB. I assume anyone knowledgeable enough to help with this would already know that most USB cameras do not support the implemented preferences. I will be clearer about that in the future

Comment: @furas 0 was just a place holder for the code, the cameras are on ports 2, 3, 4, 8, 9,12 but thats besides the point as I stated I was getting an image with poor contrast not that I was getting the wrong image.
All cameras correctly give me an image I can just barely see anything in it.

Comment: do you get poor contras before converting to gray ? Did you try to do it in `for`-loop to see more frames? On some computers it may need time to "worm up".

Comment: @furas Its a gray-scale image from the camera to start with. Converting to gray causes no change in image quality. 
I am unsure if there is a way to have VideoCapture produce gray scale frames to start; if that would change the outcome.

Yes I ran it for over 5 minutes with no change on all cameras.

Comment: I found question about problem with FLIR and OpenCV [Retrive frames from FLIR cameras using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024360/retrive-frames-from-flir-cameras-using-opencv) but it uses C/C++ code. Using Google `FLIR camera opencv` I see some links to other portals (Reddit, GitHub) there are other questions and modules libraries for FLIR. ie. Python module [flirpy](https://pypi.org/project/flirpy/)

Comment: ie. projects on [GitHub](https://github.com/topics/flir-cameras). For some cameras can helps to change some settings - [Boson Video and Image Capture using OpenCV 16-bit Y16](https://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3387/)

Comment: @furas thanks for the links, I am actually more familiar with C++ than python but the client is not nearly as computer literate. Only reason I was doing python.
I'll see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might know if you are working with **gray8** ("Example Image Normal, taken from cheese") or **gray16** ("Example Image Code, pre-hist, note you can see myself with a headset and a mic") images.

Here goes a good explanation:

https://youtu.be/T-XuDpsJ-g8

, extracted from this course:

https://pyimagesearch.com/2022/10/17/thermal-vision-measuring-your-first-temperature-from-an-image-with-python-and-opencv/

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33040349)